# predicate logic | truth value of a sentence

Tags: logic

what is the truth value of the next sentence:
$$\forall x\exists y(x\nsubseteq y)$$ In the world of: $P(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Hint: what does it happen if $x$ is the empty set?

Comment: $\exists x\forall y (x\subseteq y)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen maybe there's a missing "not"

Comment: @user6530 I think Hagen's remark is true, with $x=\phi.$ And the remark is the negation of the OP statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of this assertion is
$$\exists x \forall y, x\subset y$$

And this is true since for $x=\emptyset$, $\forall y,\emptyset \subset y$.

So the assertion is false.